# PHP function variable from variable

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a PHP function that ends like this:

```
// Return the thread ID.
return $message->thread_id;
```

I don't need to return the thread_id for anything other the the below. How would I then call this function which has arguments as:

```
function messages_delete_thread( $thread_ids, $user_id = 0 )
```

I have tried

```
// return $message->thread_id;  (commented out as I don't need to 'return' I just want to get this value for the next line)
messages_delete_thread(thread_id,bp_loggedin_user_id());
```

But that hasn't worked because `return` effectively ends the function - what can I do instead?

For reference, `bp_loggedin_user_id()` should be grabbing the current user.
I am using messages_new_message and messages_delete_thread from [here](https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/master/src/bp-messages/bp-messages-functions.php#L42)

Comment: When you return, it stops executing anything after that.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the next line"? When execution reaches the `return` statement, it will *return* from the current function - it won't run the line after it.

Comment: Put your `messages_delete_thread` where you called your initial function.

Comment: "I have a PHP function that ends like this" Are you wanting to call `messages_delete_thread()` after you call that function and use the result of that first function call in the second? It is quite unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @PatrickQ I've edited the question which may help clarify. I want to take `thread_id` into `messages_delete_thread`. I could take out `return`...?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your first function's name is `example`:

```
function example(){
    // some code
    return $message->thread_id;
}
```

To achieve what you want to do, you have to either store the returned result into a variable, or call it directly as a parameter of your second function.

```
$threadId = example();
messages_delete_thread($threadId, bp_loggedin_user_id());
```

Or

```
messages_delete_thread(example(), bp_loggedin_user_id());
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply assign the result of the first function to a variable, and then pass that variable into the call of the second function.

```
function firstFunction()
{
    // ... whatever the code is
    // Return the thread ID.
    return $message->thread_id;
}

$threadId = firstFunction();

messages_delete_thread($threadId,bp_loggedin_user_id());
```

Comment: Thanks. The `return $message->thread_id;' line comes at the end of this function https://buddypress.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/messages_new_message/?bwscid1=2 How can I do something similar to `$threadId = firstFunction();` in this case? :)

Comment: If you have relevant code, you should add it to your question. Most people here (myself included) are not going to follow a random link to an unknown site.